# Deploying to same server with different ruby versions

Tags: ruby, capistrano, jruby, rbenv

I wrote an import script that has grown into a full import environment.

Basicaly I can run 3 different imports by executing thor tasks.

I set up a capistrano3 deploy script to transfer all of this a server. After deployment `capistrano/whenever` will generate a crontab file to execute the import tasks at various times.

Now I ran into the problem, that I need a different ruby version for one of the imports (MRI instead of JRuby).

I am currently using rbenv (I don't want to switch to rvm). I thought that the easiest way would be to deploy to 2 directories (e.g. /srv/ruby/app/mri and /srv/ruby/app/jruby) and defining the ruby versions as roles (i also need staging and production environment).

I already took a look at capistrano/multiconfig but I cannot wrap my head around it.

Someone did something similar or hash experience on how to do that?